# Increase font size of rendered comments in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In Android Studio, the comments can be rendered to look more readable. But it seems that their font size if fixed and doesn't follow the "roll the mouse wheel to increase the font size" mechanism.
Is there a way to increase the font size of the comments?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right click on the comment, Adjust font size in the context menu:

[image: adjust font size]

Vote for this issue

- [IDEA-238153](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-238153) Make rendered JavaDoc font size bigger/smaller when zooming in/out on code